# Can particles (atoms, protons, neutrons and quarks) combine together in empty space?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, astrophysics, nucleosynthesis

Can particles (atoms, protons, neutrons and quarks) combine together in empty space without the use of energy to form macroscopic objects? Can elements form with an atomic number that is greater than the elements one started out from, in empty space?

Answer (score 2):

To quote Old Ben Kenobi: “Of course I know him.  He’s me.”  I, an assemblage of atoms, formed from empty space.  It took me a long time, though, and I had to discard a lot of detritus. Also I have to constantly exchange a small fraction of my atoms with a reservoir I keep nearby, or I stop being interesting.  I share this reservoir with a number of peers, including (almost certainly) you.

In the first moments after the Big Bang, some number of protons, neutrons, electrons, and neutrinos condensed out of the initial hot plasma as it cooled.  About three-quarters of the protons and neutrons stayed single; these became hydrogen nuclei (after the neutrons had decayed).  About one-quarter of the protons and neutrons bound together to form helium.  There was some production of other low-mass elements at this time, up to lithium, but they are basically rounding error compared to hydrogen and helium-4.  The formation of heavier elements and complex macrostructures took more time, and required the formation (from empty space) and destruction of a number of stars.

In a comment, you mention Boltzmann brains.  This silly idea comes from a computation that an isolated brain having a brief solipsist delusion has less entropy than an entire universe full of matter, and is therefore more likely to exist. It’s clear that the Boltzmann Brain hypothesis is somehow a misapplication of the idea of entropy.  (For one thing, there are clearly many more ways for a solipsist delusion to be a nonsensical fever dream than to be a universe with comprehensible laws. It’s therefore unclear why it might make sense to use our hard-fought comprehensible laws to predict that our reality is, in fact, imagined.)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I thought that actually a Boltzmann brain would have a false knowledge of the external world, but what if a computer was created instead of the brain, which then created a brain by sending electrical stimuli to it, simulating an external world?  it is very difficult, but there is a lot of time until thermal death

Comment: Every complication you add to the scenario makes it exponentially more improbable.

Comment: I know, but my goal is to find the simplest situation in which a brain can live in the distant future, at least for a few moments so that I can perhaps reject the hypothesis if it is incompatible with the reality I am living

Comment: The simplest way for a brain to exist in the distant future is as a descendant of brains which exist in the present. The statement that some models predict disembodied delusional brains is a criticism of those models, not a real prediction. Compare to the creationist proposal that the world was created in 4004 BCE, complete with fake evidence of a longer geological history and fake fossils of fake dinosaurs and fake light signals streaming towards us from fake space, to deceive geologists and paleontologists and astronomers. Delusions are, by definition, unfalsifiable.

Comment: ok I know it is unfalsifiable this does not necessarily make it false, and in any case I have not yet understood how a brain can survive and / or have the time to form without wasting away.  and note: if our best theories predict boltzmann "things" and also computers forming brains in jars, and the scenario turns out to be physically impossible or the simplest situation (see my comment above for this concept), then there is no no reason to say that our theories have critical points in them

Comment: Part of the absurdity of the Boltzmann brain scenario is that the brains *don't* survive. They fluctuate into existence, believe briefly that they are participating in an intellectual tradition which explains some fraudulent reality, and then cease to function. There is nothing special about impossibly rare fluctuations in the infinite future which happen to resemble human brains. Other (more common) fluctuations will include solved jigsaw puzzles and ordered decks of playing cards. Other (yet more common) fluctuations will include unsolved jigsaw puzzles and shuffled decks of cards.

Comment: so they form in an instant and then disappear?  isn't there a way to make them slowly form?

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself: every complicating condition you add makes the situation exponentially more improbable.

Comment: sorry for the insistence but I did not understand if they are formed instantaneously and how rare they are actually, that is, how many are produced before heat death?

Comment: Zero. The model which predicts them is wrong.

Comment: ok, sorry for the boredom I'm giving you, last question, the model is wrong due to the question that they would be inconsistent due to their distorted memories or the current physical laws do not allow it or they are just too unlikely regardless of the time

Answer (score 1):

> Can particles (atoms, protons, neutrons and quarks) combine together in empty space [...] to form macroscopic objects?

Of course, there are no free quarks, and neutrons aren't stable. But yes, for example, hydrogen atoms can combine to molecular hydrogen. Lots of molecules can assemble into proto-stellar disks. That's how solar systems form.

> Can particles (atoms, protons, neutrons and quarks) combine together in empty space without the use of energy to form macroscopic objects?

Not sure what you mean with "without the use of energy", but yes, for example, gravity alone can cluster matter.

> Can elements form with an atomic number that is greater than the elements one started out from, in empty space?

This is conceivable in principle, but my educated guess is that such processes would be super rare. But I don't see why you couldn't hit e.g. a relativistic hydrogen nucleus with a relativistic deuterium nucleus and fuse them into helium-3. The high kinetic energies you can get in extreme astrophysical environments. But not the densities by your assumption of being in "empty space" (whatever that is ;) ). So it could happen, but I very much doubt that it is relevant anywhere.

Comment: so they can form macroscopic objects like a computer, or a quantum computer?

Comment: @Zeruel017      The odds of forming a recognizable object with anything more than a few atoms are infinitesimally small.

Comment: okay but with a lot of time available it's possible, anyway i'm talking about boltzmann's brain problem

Comment: People play games with the limit of $1-(1-x)^y$ as x goes to 0 and y goes to infinity to assert that the limit is 1, not 0, no matter how small you make x, if you just make y infinite. It's adequately true philosophy but bogus physics: the point of a model in physics is to predict the outcome of a finite number of experiments.